# Byte slice converted with unsafe from string changes its address

Tags: go, pointers, garbage-collection, race-condition, unsafe

I have this function to convert string to slice of bytes without copying

```
func StringToByteUnsafe(s string) []byte {
    strh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    var sh reflect.SliceHeader
    sh.Data = strh.Data
    sh.Len = strh.Len
    sh.Cap = strh.Len
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&sh))
}
```

That works fine, but with very specific setup gives very strange behavior:

The setup is here: https://github.com/leviska/go-unsafe-gc/blob/main/pkg/pkg_test.go

What happens:

1. Create a byte slice
2. Convert it into temporary (rvalue) string and with unsafe convert it into byte slice again
3. Then, copy this slice (by reference)
4. Then, do something with the second slice inside goroutine
5. Print the pointers before and after

And I have this output on my linux mint laptop with go 1.16:

```
go test ./pkg -v -count=1
=== RUN   TestSomething
0xc000046720 123 0xc000046720 123
0xc000076f20 123 0xc000046721 z
--- PASS: TestSomething (0.84s)
PASS
ok      github.com/leviska/go-unsafe-gc/pkg     0.847s
```

So, the first slice magically changes its address, while the second isn't

If we remove the goroutine with `runtime.GC()` (and may be play with the code a little bit), we can get the both pointers to change the value (to the same one).

If we change the unsafe cast to just `[]byte()` everything works without changing the addresses. Also, if we change it to the unsafe cast from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66218124/5516391 everything works the same.

```golang
func StringToByteUnsafe(str string) []byte { // this works fine
    var buf = *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&str))
    (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf)).Cap = len(str)
    return buf
}
```

I run it with `GOGC=off` and got the same result. I run it with `-race` and got no errors.

If you run this as main package with main function, it seems to work correctly. Also if you remove the `Convert` function. My guess is that compiler optimizes stuff in this cases.

So, I have several questions about this:

0. What the hell is happening? Looks like a weird UB
1. Why and how go runtime magically changes the address of the variable?
2. Why in concurentless case it can change both addresses, while in concurrent can't?
3. What's the difference between this unsafe cast and the cast from stackoverflow answer? Why it does work?

Or is this just a compiler bug?

A copy of the full code from github, you need to put it in some package and run as test:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "sync"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

func StringToByteUnsafe(s string) []byte {
    strh := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))
    var sh reflect.SliceHeader
    sh.Data = strh.Data
    sh.Len = strh.Len
    sh.Cap = strh.Len
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&sh))
}

func Convert(s []byte) []byte {
    return StringToByteUnsafe(string(s))
}

type T struct {
    S []byte
}

func Copy(s []byte) T {
    return T{S: s}
}

func Mid(a []byte, b []byte) []byte {
    fmt.Printf("%p %s %p %s\n", a, a, b, b)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        b = b[1:2]
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("%p %s %p %s\n", a, a, b, b)
    return b
}

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    str := "123"
    a := Convert([]byte(str))
    b := Copy(a)
    Mid(a, b.S)
}
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56219270/11424673

Comment: as I said, if you run it as main, it does work correctly. But if you run it as a test, it doesn't. My guess is that if you write in main package, compiler will optimise functions, but in package it can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the github issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47247

> The backing store of a is allocated on stack, because it does not
> escape. And goroutine stacks can move dynamically. b, on the other
> hand, escapes to heap, because it is passed to another goroutine. In
> general, we don't assume the address of an object don't change.
>
> This works as intended.

And my version is incorrect because

> it uses reflect.SliceHeader as plain struct. You can run go vet on it,
> and go vet will warn you.`